# How to install aimeos in laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am new with laravel. I have no idea how to install aimeos in laravel 5.1, since the installation guide for laravel 5.0, there is a different service provider in between L5 and L5.1.

I got this error:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\classic>composer require aimeos/aimeos-laravel
Using version ^1.0 for aimeos/aimeos-laravel
./composer.json has been updated



[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
Class 'Aimeos\Shop\ShopServiceProvider' not found



Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference between Laravel 5.0 and 5.1 when installing the Aimeos web shop package:

https://aimeos.org/docs/Laravel/Install_Aimeos

**Update:**

There seems to be a problem due to a recent change in Laravel 5.1.x because the service provider is now used before composer installs the package. I've fixed this in my test installation by

- removing the the provider from config/app.php
- removing the Aimeos related artisan commands in the "scripts" section of the composer.json file
- running "composer update" afterwards with the aimeos-laravel package as requirement
- executing the artisan tasks ("vendor:publish", "migrate", "aimeos:setup", "aimeos:cache") afterwards by hand

Comment: I alredy added it to my config/app.php providers. But still get the error

Answer (score 0):

Download https://github.com/aimeos/aimeos-laravel.
      place package to root or desired folder and while updating the composer set

```
"require": {
              .......
             "laravel/framework": "^5.1.11",
             ......
             }
```

then brows

https://aimeos.org/docs/Laravel/Install_Aimeos#Laravel_5.0.2F5.1_and_Aimeos_1.0 Link and follow the instructions.